# What's the best option using cryptojs, have the key stored in client and server sides, or generate the key and pass it some way to the other side?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I want to encrypt and decrypt the data passed between the client and the server using cryptojs. To decrypt the data it is necessary to know the key used, so Imhave two options:

- Use a fixed key stored in both sides.
- Generate randomly the key and pass it to the other side with the data.

In both cases, if the petition is captured, you can resend it to the server and access to the page.

If I use a fixed key, if you get the key, you can decrypt all the messages, except if you change the key.

If I pass the key with the data, you get the key with the data (I pass in a no clear way, so you have to know what part is the key and what part is the data). But this key changes with every petition.

Anyway, I think the attacker could just see the client side code and discover the procedure used to encrypt the data and do the opposite procedure.

What's the best option?

PD: I know that https is the way, but I want tp do this too.

Comment: These is no "best" way without describing what kind of attack scenario you want to protect from. Right now the answer is neither, because it seems you already use TLS.

Comment: I don't use https right now, because i don't know in which final server it would be working. I think it should use https, but I have no control over it.

Comment: Have you read this? https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/

Comment: So I need to include some security, although it would be vulnerable. Therefore, I want to use crypto-js in the best way I can. Now I pass all the data and the salt appended and derive the key and the iv from the salt. I have thought about generate the random salt always in the server and pass it to the client and use it there to do the encryption. I know that a MITM can capture the request of login and use it to be logged in, but, at least I wnat to avoid that he can see the user name and another data in plain text, or, at lest, do something with sense.

Comment: Anyway, security it's not a big thing in my project. In fact, it's a student project and it's not about security, it's just to add something. My work would be modified after being really used, since it would be embed into a bigger one. But for academic purposes I have to (or I want to) offer somehing complete.

Comment: Plain symmetric encryption achieves only obfuscation without proper transport security. There is no security in the options you described. If you only need obfuscation, then you can use both of your options. If you assume that the attacker is only passive (cannot inject/manipulate the JavaScript of your page) then you can use both of Wand Maker's approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option: 1**

Assuming that you want to use CryptoJS and you want to use HTTP, and you don't want the attacker to know the secret key, you can use [PBKDF2](http://%60https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/%60).

> PBKDF2 is a password-based key derivation function

You can generate a key from the user's password on browser and use it to encrypt the data encryption key.

On server side, assuming that you will have access to user's password from the user database, you can re-generate the same PBDKF2 key using the password and decrypt the data encryption key.

Once both server and client have agreed on a shared data encryption key, they can have future exchange of data using that key.  In this process, a hacker may not get access to the data encryption key as it was exchanged in encrypted form.  Also, it requires a human to enter a password whose value hacker is not aware of.

***NOTE 1:*** This solution will not work if you are authenticating user against third party authentication provider and you do not have access to user's password.

***NOTE 2:*** CryptoJS seems to support only symmetric ciphers - hence, there will be a need to exchange key between client and server.  The key has to be exchanged via a shared secret that is not shared using the same channel on which key will be used.

**Option: 2**

If you cant use PBDKF2 for some reason, and still want to exchange keys securely between client and server, then, you will have to employ asymmetric encryption.  A library [JSEncrypt](http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/) provides RSA encryption.

If this library is employed, then, client (browser) can generate a key usng CryptoJS and encrypt it with a RSA public key using JSEncrypt and send the encrypted key to server.  Server can decrypt the encrypted-key using RSA private key.  This process will result in safe exchange of key.

Comment: I'm not sure if Icould do that, since I hash the password twice, one on client side using sha-3 and another on the server side with crypt, so the passwords in both sides are different.

Comment: About option 2. If I want to encrypt data in server side ans decrypt in client side. I would use private key to encrypt and public to decrypt, don't I? WOuld it be best to use this instead of cryptojs to encrypt data, not only the key? Do I need to add some php library?

Comment: If you encrypt anything using private key, then, anyone with public key can decrypt it - such schemes are used only for message authenticity - to prove who sent the message (as in digital signature) - it cannot be used for security.  The idea is to create a symmetric key on client and send it safely to server by encrypting it using public key - server can send response back by encrypting it using symmetric key itself - since client already has the symmetric key, it can decrypt server response.  If attacker has browser access, he can still sniff symmetric key from Javascript global object/DOM

Comment: Ok. I have tried And I thinl it would work. If the symmetric key is generated randomly and stored into a function variable, it's still accessible from DOM ?